# sklearn: Measuring similarities between different sets of independent variables

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, similarity

Suppose, we have

```
 points1 = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [0,1],[1,0]])
 points2 = np.array([[2,1], [0,0], [1,0],[0,1]])
```

Now they are ordered by construction. However this is just a MVE and in my application, the elements of each array will be shuffled. (Here we can just use `np.random.shuffle()` ).

If you look at the dataset, you can see that 3 of the elements are the same points, while only one of them changes. In other words:

- `[0,0]` in `points2` is the closest point to `[0,0]` in `points1`, and `[0,0]` in `points1` is the closest point to `[0,0]` in `points2`.
- `[0,1]` in `points2` is the closest point to `[0,1]` in `points1`, and `[0,1]` in `points1` is the closest point to `[0,1]` in `points2`.
- `[1,0]` in `points2` is the closest point to `[1,0]` in `points1`, and `[1,0]` in `points1` is the closest point to `[1,0]` in `points2`.
- `[0,1]` , `[1,0],` `[2,1]` in `points2` are the closest points to `[1,1]` in `points1` and `[1,1]` in `points1` is the closest point to `[2,1]` in `points2`

Notice how I specified both ways! Indeed one point in the first list could be the closest to a point in the second list, but the inverse might not be true! (I.e. there could be a point in the second list that is actually the closest to that same point in the first list).

Also, notice that in the last bullet point we have 3 points which are closest to `[1,1]`. However, in the case that multiple points are closest to a given point, I want to eliminate those that have already found a *different* closest point. For instance in the last bullet point I would keep `[2,1]` in `points2` as the closest point to `[1,1]` , since `[0,1]` in `points2` considers `[0,1]` in `points1` as its closest and similarly `[1,0]` in `points2` considers `[1,0]` in `points1` as its closest, so they are already "shipped" or "busy".

**My problem**

Now given two arrays of the same dimensions (as above), i.e. they contain the same number of points, I want to be able to find a match (or matches if there isn't a unique one) such that:

- each point in `points1` is matched to one and only one point in `points2`. And such that each point in `points2` is matched to one and only one point in `points1`.
- These matches are given by the fact that they are the closest. Imagine that I had only one of those lists of points and I applied a random shock to each point. Then I want to basically "guess" where each point went (and they should be the closest, but never mind this part).

How can I do that?

**My Try**

1. First of all I tried writing a function that would loop through the points in `points1` and for each of them, would compute the distance to each of the points in `points2`. After this, I would go through each of these distance-lists, order them and find the minimum. Thus I would match each point to the one with the minimum distance. However this falls into the problem that if a is closest to be, it doesn't imply that b is closest to a, and thus you can end up with matches where many points are then matched to one point and so on.

   2. I tried with `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min(Y,X)` as you can read [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min) but it seems to be doing something slightly different from what I want since again doesn't match each point to one and only one. (Or better, in the output it does, actually I think it just chooses it based on which point was declared as closest first)

Do you have any suggestions?

Basically given two lists of points (of the same size) I want to match the points by distance (any distance metrics would be fine I guess, maybe Euclidean and Manhattan would be best). If possible after this matching has been found, I would like to be able to output a "similarity score". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate all of the distances between all of the elements in list1 and list2. Order these distances. (Actually these will be objects containing the distance AND references to the two endpoints) Get the smallest distance and pair the endpoints of this distance. 
Then get the next smallest distance where none of the endpoints are paired yet. Continue until all of the points are paired.

Unfortunately this algorithm has O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. As long as you have to compare list with only a few hundreds (or maybe thousands) of elements it will work. Above that it could be extremely slow...

Comment: Thank you Selindek! Do you know of any implementation of this algorithm in Python?

Comment: Would this be something like Kruskal's algorithm?